# Bubbleplot with seaborn

Tags: python, plotting, seaborn

Is there someway to create a bubble plot with seaborn? I already know how to do it with Matplot lib, as in [this tutorial](https://python-graph-gallery.com/270-basic-bubble-plot/).

```
# libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
# create data
x = np.random.rand(40)
y = np.random.rand(40)
z = np.random.rand(40)
 
# use the scatter function
plt.scatter(x, y, s=z*1000, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I would like to replicate this with Seaborn. I am able to plot, but cannot control the size of marker.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
data=pd.DataFrame({"x":x, "y":y,"z":z})
sns.lmplot(x="x", y="y",data=data,  fit_reg=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796451/changing-the-marker-size-in-python-seaborn-lmplot) in stackoverflow. Anyhow just to recap quickly, you can do it with:

```
scatter_kws={"s": 10}
```

And in your case it is simply:

```
sns.lmplot(x="x", y="y",data=data,  fit_reg=False,scatter_kws={"s": z*1000})
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the original question, this works great!